# Chrome extension: Send message from background script to *all* tabs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to have the background script inform *all* currently open tabs (i.e. their content scripts) that an event took place.

Something like the following basically

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage("*", {foo: "bar"})
```

I suspect I could maintain a list of open tabs on the background script, if that's possible, and use that. But is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The wildcard is not supported. The only way to reach all tabs is to [query](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query) all existing tabs, and dispatch the message using [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-sendMessage).

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    var message = {foo: bar};
    for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; ++i) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Rob W's example.  This is probably a little better:

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => tabs.forEach( tab => chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, message) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

async/await way:

```js
const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({});

  for (const tab of tabs) {
    if (!tab.id) return;
    try {
      // send message to tab
      const response = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, message);
    } catch (e: any) {
      console.error("Error: ", e);
    }
  }
```