# Do broadcast messages respect the "matches" policy?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16046641/962893) to do a broadcast from the popup page to all the tabs, and it works perfectly fine. I just wanted to know if the message is sent to all the pages or just the pages precised in the manifest: In this case youtube.com

```
"content_scripts": [ {
      "matches": [
        "*://www.youtube.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["some/script.js"]
   } ]
```

### Edit

Only the youtube pages will handle the message because they are the only ones to have the listener. **But is it a good practice?** Shouldn't I try to just send the message to the good pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the method described in the solution you linked, it's easy to restrict it to only tabs that match a certain pattern, just include `url` field in the queryInfo parameter to `tabs.query`:

```
chrome.tabs.query({url:'*://www.youtube.com/*'}, function(tabs) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know it was possible

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you content scripts will be loaded to youtube pages only. Thus no messages listeners on other website pages