# Communication between page and extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

i develop my first chrome extension.

I try to call the page from my `default_popup`.

I try with the `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` and the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` but that do not work.

I read this page https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging, but i can't figure out where to place correctly my Listiner.

I need when i open the "default popup", call an event in the page and return something to the "default_popup" came from the page.

More explication :

Actually i have a content.js in this content.js i am able to call the background.js by calling the chrome.runtime.sendMessage but it's call to fast.

The DOM of the page have not enought time to load. My content.js  inject some .js file in the webpage to interact with the page.

It's there a way i can call the crhome.extension.sendMessage from the injected page ?

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Use chrome.**tabs**.sendMessage with a tab id to send to the content script's onMessage listener ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16046641)). P.S. replace `apps` with `extensions` in the docs link.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for your answer, but the problem is from the background script i can't get the "html content" on the webpage where i am ..

Comment: Uhm, if `I try to call the page` means access to web page DOM, you need a content script for that. Make sure you've read the extension [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry i realise i was unclear. I add more details on my problem. i already have a content.js file

Comment: Without the actual code it's hard to guess what exactly seems to be the problem here so I can only suggest reading the documentation, studying [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples). In case you need something from the page's JS context, see [Access global js variables from js injected by a chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/46870005)

Comment: @wOxxOm how would extend this to the question (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76030639/how-to-communicate-between-react-webapp-and-react-extension-when-extension-is-cl]

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found it.

We can register in the background.js an event

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
 function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
   debugger;
   if (sender.url == blacklistedWebsite)
     return;  // don't allow this web page access
   if (request.openUrlInEditor)
     openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
 });
```

You need to put in the manifest the right rules

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

After that from your injected page :

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID, { openUrlInEditor: "test" },
  function (response) {
    debugger;
    if (!response.success)
      handleError("est");
  });
```